# How do I retrieve a list within dictionary within a list?

Tags: python

How do I retrieve a list value, within a dictionary, that's within a list?

```
x = [{'name': 'joe', 'items': ['hat','scarf','boots']},
{'name': 'john', 'items': ['jeans','shirt','jacket']}]
```

x is considered a list type variable, and I'm trying to pull just the values within the list called 'items'.

Calling x[0] will load the first list item which includes name and items for joe, but not sure how to pull only the items. x[0][0] of course doesn't work because it's also part of a dictionary.

Comment: `x[0]['items'][0] == 'hat'`

Comment: Many thanks Finwood! I feel a bit silly that I didn't call the particular key. It did the job and my script is now working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You access it just as you would think intuitively. Access the first element in your list, and then the list element at index 0 for your respective dict:

```
>>> print(x[0]['items'][0])
hat
```

***The logical progression***

```
>>> print(x[0])
{'name': 'joe', 'items': ['hat', 'scarf', 'boots']}

>>> print(x[0]['items'])
['hat', 'scarf', 'boots']

>>> print(x[0]['items'][0])
hat
```

Comment: Thank you for breaking it down logically.

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you mean?:

```
x[0]['items']
```

Comment: Boy do I feel silly now, that's exactly what I was looking for. Still new to python, so thanks for taking the time to share.